# Toggle Color of Button Added To Favorites in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm displaying a list of items and user has ability to add an item to their Favorites.

My issue is that I'm only capturing one favorite state, thus, on click of one button, all of the item buttons (red heart below) change color.

[image]

I'm trying to work through the best way to handle the toggling of a favorite item.

Here's the button code and the corresponding click handler:

```
<Table.Cell textAlign="center">
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => addFavorite(card, props.loggedUser)}
                      bordered
                      color={favorite ? "google plus" : "twitter"}
                      icon={favorite ? "heart" : "heart outline"}
                    />
                  </Table.Cell>

 const addFavorite = (card, user) => {
    console.log("CARD + USER ON CLICK", card, user);
    props.updateUser(card, user);
    setFavorite(!favorite);
  };
```

On click, i'm sending the favorite to the user's favorite array in database and this works successfully.  (although I'm not handling any removal yet).

I also, set the state as shown with the setFavorite call above, however this is just tracking one universal 'favorite' state and not the favorite state for each item.

```
const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState("false");
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this.  Should i be adding a state that holds all of the favorites?

I do have a store/state available called loggedUser which contains all of the user's information and favorite items.  Should i be running a check against that maybe?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Another way may be just store the ID of this favourite in an array of the component state and in props just check for them
```
this.state = {
    likeIds = [1,5,6]
}

//Inside For loop
<div><Button data-id={key}  color={this.state.likeIds.contain(key) ? "google plus" : "twitter"} icon={this.state.likeIds.contain(key) ? "heart" : "heart outline"}

const addFavorite = (key, user) {
    this.setState({
        likeIds: [...likeIds, key] 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you mentioned in above answer, to keep the data even you refresh the page, you should save the favorite array in localstorage.

```
const [favorites, setFavorite] = useState("");

useEffect(async ()=>{
  let savedFavorite = await localStorage.getItem('__Fav');
  if(savedFavorite) {
    setFavorite(savedFavorite);
  }
}, [])
```

Inside addFavoirte you can check if the clicked one is already in favorite array. If it is in there you can just remove it and save the new favorite array to the localstorage.
if it not in the favorite array you can just push it and save the new array to the localstorage again.

So now, if you reload the page useEffect will fetch the savedFavorite array and add it to the favorite array in the component.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `<FavoriteButton>` component, and within the button instantiate your `favorite` state. React will treat each of these `<FavoriteButton>`s as unique with their own set of state.

Best practice would probably be to create a component that handled returning your entire `<Table.Row>`s and have state be managed on a per-row basis.

Answer (score 1):

Another way may be just store the ID of this favourite in an array of the component state and in props just check for them

```
this.state = {
    likeIds = [1,5,6]
}

//Inside For loop
<div><Button data-id={key}  color={this.state.likeIds.contain(key) ? "google plus" : "twitter"} icon={this.state.likeIds.contain(key) ? "heart" : "heart outline"}

const addFavorite = (key, user) {
    this.setState({
        likeIds: [...likeIds, key] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Favorite` is type boolean so `color={favorite ? "google plus" : "twitter"}` will fulfil if Favorite is true. It will affect each and every button in the component. You need to save a unique id that can be used to identify each table row in the table.

For example if you are looping through data to create rows,

```
data.map((item,index) => {
  <Row>
    <Button 
      key={index} 
      onClick={()=>handleClick(index)}>
      color={favorite==index ? 'red' : 'blue'}/>
  </Row>
})
```

Now in handleClick,

```
const handleClick = (id:number) => {
  setFavoirte(id);
}
```

And if a user can select multiple favourite items then you can use arrays for `favorite`.

```
const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState([]);

const handleClick = (id:number) => {
  setFavoirte([...favorite, id]);
}

data.map((item,index) => {
  <Row>
    <Button 
      key={index} 
      onClick={()=>handleClick(index)}>
      color={favorite.indexOf(index) > 0 ? 'red' : 'blue'}/>
  </Row>
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the great input so far.  I've sort of come up with an answer that's based on a combination of responses.  The only issue is that while the favorite is added to the state on click, it is not removed if you click afterwards.  Also having a similar issue, that if i refresh the page, the buttons are all set back to   Here's what I have. Any idea how to fix?

```
const [favorites, setFavorite] = useState("");

const addFavorite = (card, user) => {
    console.log("CARD + USER ON CLICK", card, user);
    props.updateUser(card, user);
    setFavorite([...favorites, card.id]);
  };

   {!filteredData
        ? "Sorry No Cards Found"
        : filteredData.map(card => (
            <Table.Row key={card.id}>
                     //////MORE STUFF HERE

                  <Button
                  onClick={() => addFavorite(card, props.loggedUser)}
                  bordered
                  color={
                    favorites.includes(card.id) ? "google plus" : "twitter"
                  }
                  icon={
                    favorites.includes(card.id) ? "heart" : "heart outline"
                  }
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setFavorite([...favorites, product._id]);
       const favUniq = favorites.find((item) => item === product._id);
       if (favUniq) {
         const favoritsUniq = favorites.filter((item) => item !== product._id);
         setFavorite([...favoritsUniq]) ;
```